# Howto Plot ROC curve in R with only known SN/PPV/Cutoff info

Tags: r, curve, roc

Given such data:

```
#Cutpoint         SN   (1-PPV)
5       0.56    0.01
7       0.78    0.19
9       0.91    0.58
```

How can I plot ROC curve with R that produce similar result like the
attached [image]?

I know ROCR package but it doesn't take such input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to create the plot (without that silly interpolation spline between points) then just plot the data you give in the standard way, prepending a point at (0,0) and appending one at (1,1) to give the end points of the curve.

```
## your data with different labels
dat <- data.frame(cutpoint = c(5, 7, 9),
                  TPR = c(0.56, 0.78, 0.91),
                  FPR = c(0.01, 0.19, 0.58))

## plot version 1    
op <- par(xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
plot(TPR ~ FPR, data = dat, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), type = "n")
with(dat, lines(c(0, FPR, 1), c(0, TPR, 1), type = "o", pch = 25, bg = "black"))
text(TPR ~ FPR, data = dat, pos = 3, labels = dat$cutpoint)
abline(0, 1)
par(op)
```

**To explain the code:** The first `plot()` call sets up the plotting region, without doing an plotting at all. Note that I force the plot to cover the range (0,1) in both axes. The `par()` call tells R to plot axes that cover the range of the data - the default extends them by 4 percent of the range on each axis.

The next line, `with(dat, lines(....))` draws the ROC curve and here we prepend and append the points at (0,0) and (1,1) to give the full curve. Here I use `type = "o"` to give both points and lines overplotted, the points are represented by character 25 which allows it to be filled with a colour, here black.

Then I add labels to the points using `text(....)`; the `pos` argument is used to position the label away from the actual plotting coordinates. I take the labels from the `cutpoint` object in the data frame.

The `abline()` call draws the 1:1 line (here the `0`, and `1` mean an intercept of `0` and a slope of `1` respectively.

The final line resets the plotting parameters to the defaults we saved in `op` prior to plotting (in the first line).

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image]

It isn't an exact facsimile and I prefer the plot using the default for the axis ranges(adding 4 percent):

```
plot(TPR ~ FPR, data = dat, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), type = "n")
with(dat, lines(c(0, FPR, 1), c(0, TPR, 1), type = "o", pch = 25, bg = "black"))
text(TPR ~ FPR, data = dat, pos = 3, labels = dat$cutpoint)
abline(0, 1)
```

[image]

Again, not a true facsimile but close.

Comment: I have to rush to a meeting. If you need more explanation, I'll add that when I get back.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a treasure!
BTW, how can I generalize this code to include multiple lines, (i.e. more than 1 series of cut-off,tpr and fpr)

Comment: Add additional lines using repeated calls to the line `with(dat, lines(....))` where you'd need to replace `dat` with the data frame containing the second series of cutoffs. In the call to `lines()` you can adjust the plotting character and line type plus colour of lines and points to help you distinguish which series is which. If you want to label them, then you need an extra `text(....)` line too for each new `with(dat, lines(....))` line you add.

Comment: Just came along this... @Gavin, am I missing something? 1 - PPV IMHO is something quite different from FPR - the denominator is different! And I don't see how we could calculate the FPR = 1 - specificity from sensitivity and PPV without knowing the prevalence/class frequency/prior probabilities!? (assuming SN = sensitivity = TPR)

Comment: @cbeleites Well I didn't calculate anything - I just plotted the values the OP had calculated. The 1-specificity is quoted quite often in the medical ROC literature where I picked up most of this from.

Comment: @Gavin: yes, sure 1 - specificity is used very commonly. But the OP doesn't have specificity! He has PPV = Pr (correct | **prediction** was positive) whereas specificity = Pr (correct | **ground truth** was negative)